# Static class with instance variable works until I intoduce another variable into the static class that is static

Tags: c#, oop, static

```
static class Program
{
     static void Main()
     {
         DatabaseQueueLoader loader = new DatabaseQueueLoader();
         MFilesClient client = new MFilesClient();
         client.Connect();
     }
}


static class Program
{
     static void Main()
     {
         DatabaseQueueLoader loader = new DatabaseQueueLoader();
         private static NLogger logger = NLogger.UniqueInstance;
         MFilesClient client = new MFilesClient();
         client.Connect();
     }
}
```

The snippet on the top works, but the snippet on the bottom does not.  My understanding is that in a static class, one would need to have all of its members static.  This is code that I inherited and I am trying to get a full understanding for what is going on.  I do not understand why this the top version of code is working.  That might help me to figure out why when I introduce the static member, it does not work anymore.  I would also like to know why the static member is breaking it.  I can work around this in several ways, but want to gain a deeper understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use private keyword nor static inside a method. You can only use it inside a class thats why the bottom one is not working.

Comment: And the instance variables inside of a static method work because they are local variables?

Answer (score 0):

The "private static NLogger logg.." is incorrect. Variables themselves do not need to be labeled static when inside a method. You do not need to declare a variable for NLogger if the NLogger class is static, you can instead reference the method in that class directly. If NLogger is not static but an object that needs to be declared, then remove the static from that variable and declare it normally.